# How can I find out why I cannot add any product to the cart?

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, debugging

We are suddenly experiencing a problem on our site where we cannot add any product on our website to the cart.  This just started happening within the past 48 hours, but nothing has changed.
The odd part, is that no error is generated, no log is generated, It simply hands after clicking add to cart, and it just spins. No response after that (we've let it sit for 1hr, to no avail).

We've tried clearing out the /pub/static, /var/cache sessions cache di page_cache view_preprocessed, and the problem persists.  No errors show up and I cannot seem to find a rhyme or reason as to the cause.

Is there some way to turn on debugging after I click a button (but nothing else happens) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you're not able to add a product to the cart, it's often a cookie domain issue.

One place to check is to make sure that nobody changed anything in the cookie domain area in the admin area - Stores --> Configuration --> General --> Web:
 [image: Cookie Domain Setting]

If you had been using the www or subdomain version of the site, but now you're not using that, the cookie domain should help troubleshoot that this is the actual issue.

If the cookie domain setting doesn't help, then yes, I'd run the network check tool in your browser (developer tools).

And if that doesn't work, try putting the site into developer mode and see if you can get any more error handling to show up.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you!!! Your absolutely correct. 48hrs ago, we enabled GeoIP forwarding and started to split by sub-domains.  Our cookie was set to www.website.com instead of just website.com.  removing the www. at the start resolved my problem.

Thank you for such a stupid oversight on my part, and yet such simple fix!

Comment: No worries at all... very happy to help!